# Как составить правило htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Кусок из htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Но при запросе ajax файла - http://domain/admin/ajax/get_params.php открывает не совсем то (стучится в контроллер, а нужен именно файл в директории admin/ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить вот это:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Перед регулярками, которые парсят адрес.